# swiftkey keyboard won't show for react-native text input

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-text, swift-keyboard

I am having a problem with react-native textinput. on one screen the swiftkeyboard shows and on the other it does not show swift keyboard but the default keyboard.

on the below textinput swiftkey keyboard shows:

```
<TextInput
              name="hintText"
              enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = {true}
              returnKeyType = "done"
              maxLength={this.state.maxHintLength}
              multiline={true}
              placeholder="Enter your hint here"
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
              value={user.hintText}
              onChange={this.onHintTextChange}
              autoCorrect={false}
              style={styles.buttonEditTextBlue}
              blurOnSubmit={true}
            />
```

And on the below textinput swiftkey keyboard does not show

```
<TextInput
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
              value={user.email}
              onChange={this.handleEmail}
              enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = {true}
              type="text"
              keyboardType = "email-address"
              returnKeyType = "done"
              autoCorrect={false}
              style={{color:'#333333',height: 40, backgroundColor:'white', marginTop:5,width:'100%',borderRightWidth: 0, borderLeftWidth:0,borderColor: 'lightgray', borderWidth: 1,paddingLeft:10}}
            />
```

Comment: For the ones that show the default keyboard, is `secure-text` set to true?

Comment: be specific while adding a question, share your code and what you tried?